# Twitter sentiment package issues npm

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, npm, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to build a twitter sentiment analysis tool with Angular, Node and Express. Right now I am able to grab user tweets, remove *some special characters and then when I call the sentiment function it returns input.lowercase is not a function. I tried using the package Sentimental instead and it returned a very similar error.

```
 router.post("/postUsername", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.userName);
  var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: ,
    consumer_secret: '',
    access_token_key: '',
    access_token_secret: ''
  });


  client.get('statuses/user_timeline', {screen_name: req.body.userName, count:20}, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if (!error) {
      var concatenatedTweets = analyzeIt.analyzeIt(tweets);
      console.log(concatenatedTweets);
      var score = sentiment(concatenatedTweets);
      console.log(score);
      }
  });
});
```

and my analyze it function *function doesn't work the way I'd wanting to removing things

```
function analyzeIt(data) {
  return data.map(function(item){
    var puncutaionLess = item.text.replace("/[.,#!$%^&*;:{}=-_`~()]/g@?" , '');
    var finalString = puncutaionLess.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
    return finalString.replace("#@" , "");
  });
};
```

Any help would very much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expressios is weird.

First there are no quotations around regex in javascript.

Also you are not escaping special charaters:

```
   item.text.replace("/[.,#!$%^&*;:{}=-_`~()]/g@?" , '');
```

should be:

```
   item.text.replace(/[\.,#!$%^&*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g , '');
```

notice the escape of `.`

You may want to add `[]` in there too:

So for example:

```js
text = "hello[!] there!";
text = text.replace(/[\.\[\],#!$%^&*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g , '');

 console.log(text)
```

Comment: After implementing your fix,it still says input.toLowercase is not a function in the sentiment analyze function.

Comment: `toLowerCase` is a String method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) not sure what you're using it on, (also it's not toLowercase it's `toLowerCase`)

Comment: and nowhere in your code does "toLowerCase"  show up, so I don't even know what it has to do with the question

Comment: I was trying to pass an array to a function that requires the data type to be a string